# Preserving order in a ThreadPool : how to insert row into csv at specific index position?

Tags: ruby, csv, threadpool

I am writting a ruby script that loops over a csv file and then for each row retrieves data from a third party api and then writtes the retrieved data into a csv file.
 I am trying to implement a thread_pool in order to process the api calls and the insert of the rows in parallel. I am not exactly sure if what I am doing is right, so any suggestion advice is welcome.
One specific issue I am bumping on is **how to preserve the order of the original file**.
My solution would be to **pass the index** of the first file to the thread and then to force the thread to insert the row at that index position into the csv.

Here's the task class that I wish to multithread.

```
class Task
  def initialize(row, index, conn)
    @row = row
    @index = index
    @file = CSV.open("temp_and_cases_parallel.csv", "ab")
    @conn = conn
  end

  def run
    get_climate_data
    writte_climate_data
  end

  private

  def get_climate_data
    uri = "https://weather.visualcrossing.com/VisualCrossingWebServices/rest/services/weatherdata/history?&aggregateHours=24&startDateTime=#{@row["day"].strip}T00:00:00&endDateTime=#{@row["day"].strip}T23:59:00&unitGroup=metric&contentType=csv&location=#{@row["lat"].strip},#{@row["long"].strip}&key=#{API_KEY}"
    response = @conn.get uri
    puts("calling #{uri}")
    @climate_info = CSV.parse(response.body, headers: true).first
  end

  def writte_climate_data
    if @index == 1
      headers = @row.headers + @climate_info.headers
      @file << headers
    end
    @file << @row.fields + @climate_info.fields
  end
end
```

So it is in `writte_climate_data` that I would like to be able to insert into `@file` at a specific position based on `@index`

Here's the threadpool implementation :

```
class ThreadPool
  def initialize(size: 10)
    @size = size
    @tasks = Queue.new
    @pool = []
  end

  def schedule(*args, &block)
    @tasks << [block, args]
  end

  def start
    Thread.new do
      loop do
        next if @pool.size >= @size
        task, args = @tasks.pop
        thread = Thread.new do
          task.call(*args)
          end_thread(thread)
        end
        @pool << thread
      end
    end
  end

  def inactive?
    @tasks.empty? && @pool.empty?
  end

  def end_thread(thread)
    @pool.delete(thread)
    thread.kill
  end

end
```

The script that reads from cases_by_region.csv and for each line creates a thread with a Task :

```
RETRY_OPTIONS = {
  max: 10,
  interval: 3,
  interval_randomness: 0.5,
  backoff_factor: 2
}

conn = Faraday.new do |f|
  f.request :retry, RETRY_OPTIONS
end

threads = []

thread_pool = ThreadPool.new
thread_pool.start
# CSV.open("temp_and_cases_parallel.csv", "ab") do |temp_and_cases|
  CSV.foreach("cases_by_region.csv", headers: true).first(10).each_with_index do |row, index|
    thread_pool.schedule do
      Task.new(row, index, conn).run
    end
  end
# end

sleep(1) until thread_pool.inactive?
```

How would you go on achieving this, How can I preserve the original row position from the original file in the resulting csv ?

Comment: Run it the way you have it and when it's complete sort the resulting CSV by the sort order of the original CSV.

Comment: @anothermh I have followed your approach in (here)[ https://gist.github.com/davidgeismar/a88932313b36811ae6be4a0f59677385]. However Im afraid the rows variable where I store all data my become too big(it will have something like 250k entries). I would rather batch process the original csv 1000 lines by 1000 lines and writte progressively into the target file csv. However I m not sure how to do that, and havent found any batch processing methods in the CSV ruby lib. Any suggestions ?

Comment: Your link is broken. See [Markdown help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#links) for instructions for making a link. For your CSV, write the data to a new CSV. Next, read the original CSV and get the sort order. Then read your new CSV and re-sort its data by the sort order of the original. Finally, write that newly sorted data to disk.

Answer (score 0):

If you need order - you shouldn't use an Array.  You can try an Array of Hashes.

```
irb(main):001:0> a = {id: 1, name: "a"}
=> {:id=>1, :name=>"a"}
irb(main):002:0> b = {id: 2, name: "b"}
=> {:id=>2, :name=>"b"}
irb(main):003:0> c = {id: 3, name: "c"}
=> {:id=>3, :name=>"c"}
irb(main):004:0> array = [c, a, b]
=> [{:id=>3, :name=>"c"}, {:id=>1, :name=>"a"}, {:id=>2, :name=>"b"}]
irb(main):006:0> array.sort_by {|h| h[:id] }
=> [{:id=>1, :name=>"a"}, {:id=>2, :name=>"b"}, {:id=>3, :name=>"c"}]
```

I created the array with the hashes ordered 'c, a, b' and then you just sort_by the key that you want.  In this case, I used an 'id' key to make it straight-forward.  You could sort by an ID based on the row, or any other identifier that keeps things ordered as you wish (some value already present in the CSV, perhaps a timestamp)